# How to save two EditText values ​in a key

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code

```
final String name = subjectEditText.getText().toString();
final String desc = descEditText.getText().toString();

String DateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("products/" + DateNow);
myRef.setValue(name, desc);
```

But the two values ​​are not being saved, only the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [second value you pass to `setValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) is being set as the priority of the node. This priority isn't visible in the Firebase console, but it stored and retrieved through the API. If you get a `DataSnapshot` for the node, you can use [`getPriority()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getPriority()) to get the `desc` back.

Priorities are mostly a leftover from the olden days of this API, and serve very little useful purpose these days.

Nowadays if you want to store multiple values under a node, you should give them names. For example:

```
final String name = subjectEditText.getText().toString();
final String desc = descEditText.getText().toString();

String DateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("products/" + DateNow);
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("name", name);
values.put("desc", desc);
myRef.setValue(values);
```

This will create a little JSON structure under `DateNow` with:

```
{
  "name": "the name from the text field",
  "desc": "the value from the desc field"
}
```

---

You can then read these value back with:

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("database", dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        Log.i("database", dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map.

```
String DateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy", 
Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
FirebaseDatabase database = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = 
database.getReference("products/" + DateNow);
final String name = 
subjectEditText.getText().toString();

final String desc = 
descEditText.getText().toString();
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<> ();
data.put("name", name);
data.put("desc", desc);
myRef.set (data).addOnSuccussListener(...)...;
```

You can instead replace

```
data.put("name", name);
data.put("desc", desc);
```

with

```
data.put("name_desc_array", name_desc_array);
```

But you have to create array with

```
ArrayList<String> name_desc_array = new ArrayList();
name_desc_array.add ("name");
name_desc_array.add ("desc");
```

Remember, using map is the best way